# Separate hashset to run the list at several threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I googled and search here for this question and did not find anything similar to what I´m looking for.

I populated a HashSet with few objects called Person, I need to set four or five threads to search these Person in a huge text, thread seems to be the best solution for the better usage from the hardware.

The doubt is, how can I separate this HashSet and start 4 threads? I tried to create a new HashSet list and start a new thread with this new hashset divided in 4.

It seems to be a good solution but, is there a better way to do it? How can I separate the hashset and send at pieces to 4 or 5 new threads?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a producer-consumer scheme: have a single thread read the values from the hash set one by one and put them in a queue which is then processesed by several worker threads. You can use the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class to manage the workers.

**Edit**: Here's what you can do:

Define your worker class:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private Person p;

    public Worker(Person p) {
        this.p = p;
    }      

    public void run() {
        // search for p
    }
}
```

In the main thread:

```
ExecutorService s = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(Person p: hashSet) {
    s.submit(new Worker(p));
}
```

Comment: To implement the ExecutorService I need to split my HashSet and send it to be executed by the class ExecutorService?

Comment: @Rodrigo Ferrari: Yes, exactly. And you can simply send it one value at a time. The ExecutorService will manage how the threads execute the work.

Comment: Is there a simple and fast way to split this hashSet and send to the ExecutorService? A sample? I searched, but how I´m new to it, I have no idea how to sent and get a feedback from the hashSet sended. Is this a good usage? http://pcdtrabalhofinal.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/TestHash.java thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help! Just one more question, I have another hashSet called publications, where I have about 100 objects, each Person need to be searched inside these publications, following your sample, I did:

 `private Person p;
 HashSet<Publications> publications;
 
 public Searcher(Person p, HashSet<Publications> publications) {
  this.person = p;
  this.publications = publications;
 }
 
 public void run() {

  for (Publications pub : this.publications) {
                 // itarate over the publications searching for the person.
  }
  
 }`
Is this valid or not? Thanks.

Comment: I have done the script, but I´m getting a slow ended of execution, the CPU processor stop to work but the java script did not finished yeat, is there some command to terminate more faster?! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Access to a HashSet is O(1) so if you split it across multiple threads, it won't go any faster.  You are better off attempting to split the file of searching is expensive.  However if its efficient enough, one thread will be optimal.

It is worth remembering that using all the cores on your machine can mean your program is slower. If you just want to use up all the CPU on you machine, you can create a thread pool which does nothing but use up all the CPU on your machine.

Comment: It´s a processing program, it will run under the user view. The multi thread could help to go faster for searching these Person name at the text.

Comment: @RodrigoFerrari The key making sure you divide the work between threads so each thread will do 1/n of the work. If you use smaller sets in each thread, you wouldn't expect each thread to be any faster.

Comment: If you make the search fast enough, the bottle neck will be IO. In which case you need more/faster IO hardware rather than more CPU.  Having additional threads helps when you need more CPU but not more memory, disk IO, network IO, L3 cache etc.

Comment: The IO it´s ok for the time I had to execute the task, the hardware is the most advanced for small bussiness. I just need to reduce the time for searching, the memory and CPU is not a problem. Thanks.

Comment: You have to find the bottleneck and optimise for that, if you say IO, memory and CPU are not the problem, what is? You have to know what is the problem/bottleneck otherwise you won't be able to make the program faster.

Comment: The problem is the regex to find the person inside the text, it took to much time, but there is no other way to search. :(

Comment: Instead of using the regex you can use plain text searches and manipulation it can be many time faster. regex is good for convenience but not performance. If regex is you problem, CPU is your issue but I suspect once you remove regex your program will behave very differently.

Comment: Great one @peter, can you help me with it?! Show me an example? thanks

Comment: BTW: Using multiple threads will only speed up you program as many times as you have cores at best, but using more efficient code can improve the speed 10 - 1000x. It surprises me how often you can get a 1000x by just optimising the code. :-P This is why I believe you should make sure you have optimal code before considering multi-threading.

Comment: Great analysis, I looked up to use Lucene, but had no success with the indexing system, I tryed at my maximum to optimize the code, I´m using regex because a few names of persons has regex to search for. Such as: Rodrigo( )? or ( )?Rodrigo( )?

Comment: That makes some sense. If you write it as a direct lookup value. it will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to consider:

1) You could use the same HashSet, but you will need to synchronize it (wrap the calls to it with a `synchronized` block. But if all you are doing is looking up things in the hash, being multi-threaded will not buy you much.

2) If you want to split the HashSet, then you can consider a split on key ranges. So for example if you are searching for a name, names that start with A-F go in HashSet1, G-L HashSet2, etc. This way your searches can be completely parallel.

Comment: Yeah, the main idea is to split the Hashset by alphabetical order, then search in the long text for the attribute name at the class Person.

Answer (score 1):

You cane iterate through the hash set using Iterator. & while iterating fetch the value and create a thread and fire it.

Else

you can use ExecutorService API where simultaneous tasks can be run in parallel.